# show location on google map android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-maps-v2, android-location

I've a `EditText` and a `Button` I want to find location in map. I'm using `AsyncTask` to execute here is my calling of `AsyncTask` class. When I use `Toast` msg it display my location but in map it was force closed

```
new GeocoderTask().execute(location);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Here is my `GeocoderTask` class to display location in map

```
private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>>{

            @Override
            protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
                // Creating an instance of Geocoder class
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
                List<Address> addresses = null;

                try {
                    // Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input text
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 3);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }           
                return addresses;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {         

                if(addresses==null || addresses.size()==0){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                // Clears all the existing markers on the map
                googleMap.clear();

                // Adding Markers on Google Map for each matching address
                for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++){                

                    Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);

                    // Creating an instance of GeoPoint, to display in Google Map
                    latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

                    String addressText = String.format("%s, %s",
                            address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                            address.getCountryName());

                    markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    markerOptions.position(latLng);
                    markerOptions.title(addressText);

                    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                    // Locate the first location
                    if(i==0)                        
                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));     
                }           
            }       
        }
}
```

But it doesn't display location.

Comment: help me anyone plz.....

Comment: what's your problem???

Comment: i want to search my location on map

Comment: and your code is failed at which line??

Comment: i don't have any error when i trying to search it display force closed

Comment: force closed is happened with some logcat...

Comment: when i click on search button ...i

Comment: i think app is closed when i execute GeocoderTask Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you got error in line `new Geocoder(getBaseContext());`, so suggest you use constructor for passing `Context` to `AsyncTask`:

```
private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>>{

        private Context mContext;
        public GeoCoderTask(Context context) {
            super();
            mContext = context;
        }


        @Override
        protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
            // Creating an instance of Geocoder class
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext);

            ... ...

        }
}
```

Hope this help!